# Display content if within timeframe

Tags: php

I need to display some content if the current time in a certain location (say sydney, Australia) is between 9am-5pm and its a week day.

thx for any help

Comment: What is your question? What part of the task are you stuck with?

Comment: @Pekka - "If the localtime is between 9 am to 5 pm, display X".

Comment: Answered below... Jared was right about the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$current_time_date = getdate();
$currently_in_business_hours = false;

if ($current_time_date['hours'] >= 9 && $current_time_date['hours'] < 17 && $current_time_date['wday'] != 0 && $current_time_date['wday'] != 6) {

$currently_in_business_hours = true; 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into [PHP's many date/time functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php).

Here's the steps I would use:

1. Determine the local system time zone offset.
2. Determine the local system time.
3. Determine the time zone offset of the target location.
4. Knowing these items will enable you to calculate the time at the target location (subtract local offset, add target offset).
5. If the result time is between the appropriate boundaries, display the content.